# Getting TypeError: path can be only a single string when trying Stream Data in Apache Spark / Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am trying to test streaming data in Apache Spark on Databricks.

Streaming with Azure Event Hubs is relatively simple, however I'm trying stream some static data.

I first read in the static data stored in a folder called teststream using the following dataframe

```
thestream = spark.read.parquet('/mnt/lake/RAW/teststream/')
```

I then attempt to read in the data in the 'teststream' folder by convert it to a streaming query that continuously updates as data arrives using the following code:

```
streamingFlights = (spark
              .readStream
              .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1) #Treat a sequence of files as a stream by selecting one file at a time
              .csv(thestream)
            )
```

However, when I run the above I get the following error:

```
TypeError: path can be only a single string
```

Any ideas on what is causing the error?

Comment: You are trying to provide a Dataframe as the csv location. This does not work. Maybe have a look at the structured streaming programming guide to get started with spark structured streaming.

Comment: Grab free copy of Learning Spark, 2ed  from https://databricks.com/p/ebook/learning-spark-from-oreilly

Comment: @mike, I think you might not be entirely correct. This is because the following code is in the Databricks Academy course.
```streamingFlights = (spark
              .readStream
              .schema(schema)
              .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1) #Treat a sequence of files as a stream by selecting one file at a time
              .csv(flightsPath)
            )
```
And it allows you to read a stream from a csv file as the location

Comment: @Patterson then there might be a typo in your question: `csv(thestream)` where thestream ist defined with spark.read....

Answer (score -1):

The following code will emulate a stream from the files by reading them one at a time, in the chronological order they were created.

```
dataPath = "/mnt/lake/RAW/DummyEventData/"

static = spark.read.parquet(dataPath)
dataSchema = static.schema

deltaStreamWithTimestampDF = (spark
  .readStream
  .format("delta")
  .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)
  .schema(dataSchema)
  .parquet(dataPath)
)
```